# libkv / ectd go client : how to use config.TLS object?

Tags: coreos, etcd

Trying to use **docker/libkv**

https://github.com/docker/libkv#tls

which specifies that etcd and consul support TLS using a `config.TLS` object

I'm trying to figure the format of this object.

The **etcd** go client that **libkv** uses is here:

https://github.com/coreos/etcd/tree/master/client

but there is no doc about this feature and the code itself has barely any reference to TLS

So my question is 2 parts:

- Does anyone know if indeed the coreos/etcd client supports TLS? (I believe it must since docker/libkv uses it and claims to support it, but I'm having some doubts here)
- Does anyone have an example of the config.TLS object format?

Thanks for your input

PS: I did ask the question there, but figured I'll post here too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

etcd does support TLS configuration. You can find the documentation for this here: https://coreos.com/etcd/docs/latest/security.html

You can find example code for doing this here: https://github.com/coreos/etcd/blob/master/etcdctl/command/util.go#L252

In particular look for the gettransport function call that sets up the transport with TLS.

Comment: This is about etcdctl, i'm talking about the go client code as used by libkv. Or are you saying all it takes is just to define the ENV variables ?

Comment: as I understand it, to use the client.go you need to pass it a config.TLS object. I'm just trying to figure the format.

Comment: tls := transport.TLSInfo{
  CAFile:   cafile,
  CertFile: certfile,
  KeyFile:  keyfile,
 }    is that it?

Comment: etcdctl uses the same client you are talking about. I am showing you example code of how to configure TLS for that client. What am I missing? Here is the exact code for configuring a TLS transporter: https://github.com/coreos/etcd/blob/master/etcdctl/command/util.go#L156

Comment: ok, got it. thanks... the link you sent didn't point at the Transport part an that confused me at first.